# Split python string if newline starts with digit

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I try to split a text if a newline starts with a digit.

```
a="""1.pharagraph1 
    text1
    2.pharagraph2
    text2
    3.pharagraph3
    text3
    """
```

The expected result would be:

```
['1.pharagraph1 text1' , '2.pharagraph2 text2', '3.pharagraph3 text3']
```

I tried: `re.split('\n\d{1}',a)` and it doesn't work for this task.

Comment: Do you just need `[x.replace("\n"," ") for x in re.split(r'\n(?=\d)', a)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have leading spaces and you did not make a typo when creating a sample string, you can use

```py
[re.sub(r'[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*', ' ', x).strip() for x in re.split(r'\n[^\S\n]*(?=\d)', a)]
# => ['1.pharagraph1 text1', '2.pharagraph2 text2', '3.pharagraph3 text3']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3RFcot).

The `\n[^\S\n]*(?=\d)` pattern matches a newline and then any zero or more horizontal whitespaces (`[^\S\n]*`) followed with a digit. Then, inside each match, every sequence of 0+ horizontal whitespaces, newline and 0+ horizontal whitespaces is replaced with a space.

If the string has no leading whitespace, you can use a simpler approach:

```py
import re
a="""1.pharagraph1 
text1
2.pharagraph2
text2
3.pharagraph3
text3"""
print( [x.replace("\n"," ") for x in re.split(r'\n(?=\d)', a)] )
# => ['1.pharagraph1  text1', '2.pharagraph2 text2', '3.pharagraph3 text3']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/sZb2xL). Here, the string is simply split at a newline that is followed with a digit (`\n(?=\d)`) and then all newlines are replaced with a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead to only split when the newline and spaces are followed by a digit:

```
import re
result = re.split('\n\s+(?=\d)', a)
```